# calling custom delegates not working

Tags: objective-c

I have made a custom delegate:

Example.h:

```
@protocol DismissExamplePopoverDelegate
- (void) dismissExamplePopover;
- (int) getUserID;
@end


@interface Example : UIViewController{
    id<DismissExamplePopoverDelegate> delegate;
}

@property (nonatomic, assign) id<DismissExamplePopoverDelegate> delegate;
```

It is called in Example.m like follows:

```
[[self delegate] getUserID];
```

In my maincontroller.h:

```
#import "Example.h"

@interface MainScreen : UIViewController<DismissExamplePopoverDelegate>
```

maincontroller.m:

```
-(int) getUserID
{
    return 100;
}
```

the view Example is called by the following method:

```
ExampleController = [[Example alloc] initWithNibName:@"Example" bundle:nil];
ExamplePopoverController = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:ExampleController];

[ExampleController setDelegate:self];
ExamplePopoverController.popoverContentSize = CGSizeMake(600, 480);

if ([ExamplePopoverController isPopoverVisible]) {
        [ExamplePopoverController dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];
} else {
    CGRect popRect = CGRectMake((self.EditExampleSelectAddButtonProperty.frame.origin.x),
                                    (self.EditExampleSelectAddButtonProperty.frame.origin.y),
                                    (self.ExampleSelectAddButtonProperty.frame.size.width),
                                    (self.ExampleSelectAddButtonProperty.frame.size.height));
    [ExamplePopoverController presentPopoverFromRect:popRect inView:self.view permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];
}
```

If I place `[[self delegate] getUserID]` in any function other than `viewdidload` it works perfectly: returns 100; in `viewdidload` it returns 0.

What i want to achieve is a delegate to be called automatically when the popover loads. Is viewdidload the best place for it, or is there somewhere else

Comment: Where (when) do you set the `delegate` property of `Example`?

Comment: do you mean put [[self delegate] getUserID]?

Comment: No. You create an `Example` object - say `myExample`. Show this code and the code where you do `myExample.delegate = self;` (or whatever you assign to the delegate property).

Comment: You must be doing it since you said that calls to `[[self delegate] getUserID];` work in most places.

Comment: the only code i have as regards the delegate is shown above, is it possible you could give example

Comment: I gave you an example in my 2nd comment.

Comment: i dont do anything like that, im now trying to understand why this works in any other functions.

Comment: Why is the name of the delegate the MainScreen conforming to is different than the name of delegate you created?

Comment: hi there i changed the names to keep it simple, i am basing it on a example i found on the internet

Comment: Ok your code looks fine. Try this, put this line [ExampleController setDelegate:self]; above the line where you are initiating a `UIPopoverController` instance i.e. one line above.

Comment: hi there, thanks for everyone help, my stupidity made it alot harder than it appeared.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple of people have said this, but haven't been clear enough about the solution.

Instead of doing this:

```
ExampleController = [[Example alloc] initWithNibName:@"Example" bundle:nil];
ExamplePopoverController = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:ExampleController];

[ExampleController setDelegate:self];
```

Do this:

```
ExampleController = [[Example alloc] initWithNibName:@"Example" bundle:nil];
[ExampleController setDelegate:self];

ExamplePopoverController = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:ExampleController];
```

What's happening is that `-[UIPopoverController initWithContentViewController:]` uses its `contentViewController`'s `view`, causing `-[Example viewDidLoad]` to be called. Since you haven't yet set the delegate at that point, the delegate is `nil`, and attempting to call any method on `nil` returns `nil`, `0`, or `0.0`.

Comment: hi there, thanks for everyone help, my stupidity made it alot harder than it appeared.

Comment: @user2461593 You say that as though I don't do it three times a week!

Comment: i'm not saying it easy for a second, if i had to develop this code from scratch i really wouldn't have a clue, what i referred to as my stupidity was the fact people were advising me on a fix from the very beginning but i didn't realise what they were saying, think i most defiantly will stick to embedded development lol

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you're actually assigning the delegate property to MainController. For instance, wherever you've initialized Example, you need to set the delegate property:

```
Example *example = [[Example alloc] init];
example.delegate = self; // Use this if you're initializing Example in MainController
```

If you're not initializing Example in MainController, instead of "self" use the MainController instance.

Comment: i am already doing that, when i create the popover, i have edited by question to show this

Answer (score -1):

In Example.m you need to add line:

```
[self setDelegate:delegate];
```

Also, you need to `@synthesize delegate;`

Hope it help)

Comment: where do i put the @synthesize delegate, the place i assumed im getting errors. Sorry about my naivety my background is embedded

Comment: If you use XCode 4.4 or newer, you don't have to (in most cases) use @synthesize as it will be automatically done for you.

Comment: Add it after `@implementation`